# Mismatched vector sizes while connecting output port y0 of System to input port u0 of System

Tags: drake

I am learning DRAKE and going through the robotic manipulation tutorials, currently I am working through the chapter 8 examples of the point_finger. However, when I use the Planar Gripper rather than the point finger to implement the stiffness-control-based flip-up strategy. I get the following error: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched vector sizes while connecting output port y0 of System drake/systems/TrajectorySource@00000000059ea790 (size 2) to input port u0 of System drake/systems/Multiplexer@0000000005a50940 (size 3).

I have tried changing the size of the multiplexer array from [N,N] but I have not been able to properly match the vector size of the output port to the input port. What is the best way to match the vector sizes of the input and output ports?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that the gripper now has an orientation (in addition to translation), so requires 3 inputs.  You'll need a trajectory source that's outputting 3 numbers, not just two.